# Morris.js for Wordpress?

Tags: javascript

I found [Morris.js](http://oesmith.github.com/morris.js/#) to be a delightfully implemented charting script, and wanted to include it in my Wordpress installation. But I have never included a js file with my blog before, and would appreciate if someone can guide me on this:

1. How do I include the javascript file?
2. Where do I upload it on the server?
3. Anything else I need to know to use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create js folder in your theme directory then save Morris.js into it. it is not mandatory to store it in js folder you can store it anywhere else but i recommend to do it to seprate javascipt files from other files.

Add follwing action into functions.php file

```
function custom_scripts() {
/* Include Scripts */
wp_enqueue_script( 'morris-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Morris.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

You can find more information about wp_enqueue_script() function from this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script of wordpress codex.